# Keycloak admin user not created at first startup

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I am running keycloak v23.x in Kubernets.
This is the configuration:

```
apiVersion: k8s.keycloak.org/v2alpha1
kind: Keycloak
metadata:
  name: external-idp
spec:
  instances: 1
  db:
    vendor: oracle
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:XXXXXX
    schema: NSB
    usernameSecret:
      name: keycloak-db-secret
      key: KC_DB_USERNAME
    passwordSecret:
      name: keycloak-db-secret
      key: KC_DB_PASSWORD
  http:
    tlsSecret: external-idp-tls-secret
    httpEnabled: true
  hostname:
    hostname: dev-external-idp.bankinvest.dk
    strict: false
    strictBackchannel: false
  unsupported:
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: keycloak
            resources:
              requests:
                memory: "1048M"
              limits:
                memory: "1048M"
            env:
              - name: KC_PROXY
                value: edge
              - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
                value: admin
              - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
                value: admin1234
```

When I try to login to the admin console, I get the error unknown user/password.

I know the env. variable KC_PROXY works, so why not the other two?
The [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration#_creating_the_initial_admin_user) says that if you set the admin user and password an administrator will be created at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those instructions are fine when deploying keycloak "manually" -- e.g., by following [these instructions](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-kube). However, you're using the keycloak operator, which according to [the documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/operator/basic-deployment#_accessing_the_admin_console):

> When deploying Keycloak, the operator generates an arbitrary initial admin username and password and stores those credentials as a basic-auth Secret object in the same namespace as the CR.
>
> To fetch the initial admin credentials, you have to read and decode the Secret. The Secret name is derived from the Keycloak CR name plus the fixed suffix -initial-admin. To get the username and password for the example-kc CR, enter the following commands:
>
> ```
> kubectl get secret example-kc-initial-admin -o jsonpath='{.data.username}' | base64 --decode
> kubectl get secret example-kc-initial-admin -o jsonpath='{.data.password}' | base64 --decode
> ```

It is likely the operator overrides the values for `KEYCLOAK_ADMIN` and `KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD`, even when using a custom pod template.